# Do I need a UK visa (indian citizen with valid US and Schengen visa)?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I have a round trip flight from the US to London. My plans changed and now I'll be flying out from London to the Schengen Area (Barcelona). My flight from US arrives at LHR (terminal 3). I have a separate booking of a flight from LHR to Barcelona ( departing from either terminal 3 or 5). My flight to Barcelona departs on the same day as I arrive. Similarly, on the way back from Barcelona, I fly in to LHR and same day depart out to the US from LHR.

My worry is my flight to/from Barcelona fro/tom LHR is not on the same ticket as my round trip flight from the US to LHR. I have a valid schengen visa and a US visa, and I'm an Indian citizen.

Do I need a UK transit visa? Will I have to cross the immigration border in this case? Say if I have to change terminals to get to my other flight? I do not plan to check in bags.

Comment: If I do need a transit visa, I'll likely need it for both ways, and looks like they only offer transit visas for up to 48 hours, and both my flights are a week out of each other.

Comment: If you get a visitor in transit visa, they'll probably give you a single visa to cover both transits.  Each *transit* must be completed by the end of the day after arrival, but that doesn't mean that the visa itself is valid for only 48 hours.  But you should be eligible to transit without a visa, as explained in the proposed duplicate.